# Dropdown alignment issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<s:form id="inputThresholdForm" name="inputThresholdForm"
        theme="simple">

    <table border="0" class="display-table" cellspacing="2"
           cellpadding="2" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="50%"><label>Select TSP:</label></td>
            <td colspan="50%;">
                <select id="selectTspDropDown" onchange="enableSubmitButton(this.value)">
                    <option value="-1">Select TSP</option>
                </select></td>

        </tr>
```

Thus I have a form and inside that a table whose 1st row and 2nd column has a dropdown.
The dropdown gets filled with an AJAX call. So the width of data filling dropdown is large so it expands to the left. I want it to expand on  the right.

How can this be done?

Comment: you can give width using style tag like style="width:150px;" to select box

Answer (score 1):

It can but not as you might hope.

At the moment you have two widths at 50% - the problem with this is the layout engine of your browser says 'hey mr programmer - you are a little bit silly and have told me to fit data into a table cell that isn't big enough, now my opinion is that the table it the right size and so I will make the column wider to make up for this mistake.'

To fix the problem set a fixed width on the left column (select TSP: label) - but this is still not ideal as you are still forcing your browser to make a decision on how to lay things out.

Better would be to set a max-width for the drop-down itself of 100% (relative to the table cell it is in) - then your layout will not break. - this way you can leave your columns at 50% 50% and maintain your appearance.

Comment: It works with giving a fixed width of say 150px but not with 100%